# Condición entre fechas php

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de poner una condición entre dos fechas en php, pero sin contar con el año ya que todos los años se tiene que repetir igual, pero no lo consigo.

```
$Fondihoy=date("d/m");
if (($Fondihoy > "22/12") && ($Fondihoy < "07/01")) { echo "Navidad"; }
if (($Fondihoy > "08/01") && ($Fondihoy < "20/07")) { echo "Invierno"; }
```

La idea es que si estamos entre el 22 de diciembre y el 7 de enero diga que es navidad, si estamos entre el 8 de enero y el 20 de junio diga que es invierno y así con todas las estaciones, aunque me acabo de dar cuenta que me he saltado la primavera XD.

¿que tengo mal?

Había pensado en hacer el calculo con timestamp por si así no fallaba, pero claro luego he visto que timestamp también me calcula la hora y el segundo y me han dado los 7 males de pensarlo.

Edito:
ya tengo las 4 estaciones, ahora me falta saber si es navidad.

```
$Mesactual=DATE("m");     
IF ($Mesactual>="03" && $Mesactual<="05")
$Estacion = "primavera";
ELSEIF ($Mesactual>="06" && $Mesactual<="08")
$Estacion = "verano";
ELSEIF ($Mesactual>="09" && $Mesactual<="11")
$Estacion = "otono";
ELSE
$Estacion = "invierno";

echo $Estacion;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque se vaya de tu idea de trabajo, yo lo  haría de la siguiente manera

```
function saber_estacion() {

    // Guardamos en una variable el día del año
    $dia = date('z'); // Por ejemplo: "80" (empieza por 0)

    // Si la fecha actual es anterior al 21 de marzo
    if ( $dia < 79 ) {
        $estacion = 'invierno';

    // Si la fecha actual es anterior al 22 de junio
    } elseif ( $dia < 172 ) {
        $estacion = 'primavera';

    // Si la fecha actual es anterior al 23 de septiembre
    } elseif ( $dia < 265 ) {
        $estacion = 'verano';

    // Si la fecha actual es anterior al 19 de diciembre
    } elseif ( $dia < 352 ) {
        $estacion = 'otono';

    // Si no es ninguna de las anteriores
    } else {
        $estacion = 'invierno';

    }

    echo $estacion;

}
```

La idea en lugar de trabajar con fechas, es saber el dia del año, de manera númerica, al que corresponde cada fecha de inicio y final. Una vez se tiene ese dato, con `date('z')`, obtengo el valor del día de hoy y ya puedo hacer la comparación

**Editado: Para controlar años bisiestos**

```
function saber_estacion() {

    // Guardamos en una variable el día del año
    $dia = date('z'); // Por ejemplo: "80" (empieza por 0)

    // Comprobamos si es bisiesto
    $bisiesto = date('L');

    $invierno=79;
    $primavera=172;
    $verano=265;
    $otono=352;

    if( $bisiesto==1){
        $invierno=80;
        $primavera=173;
        $verano=266;
        $otono=353;
    }

    // Si la fecha actual es anterior al 21 de marzo
    if ( $dia < $invierno ) {
        $estacion = 'invierno';

    // Si la fecha actual es anterior al 22 de junio
    } elseif ( $dia < $primavera ) {
        $estacion = 'primavera';

    // Si la fecha actual es anterior al 23 de septiembre
    } elseif ( $dia < $verano ) {
        $estacion = 'verano';

    // Si la fecha actual es anterior al 19 de diciembre
    } elseif ( $dia < $otono ) {
        $estacion = 'otono';

    // Si no es ninguna de las anteriores
    } else {
        $estacion = 'invierno';

    }

    echo $estacion;

}
```

Para saber si es bisiesto uso la función `date('L')` de `PHP`, que devuelve 1 si es bisiesto o 0 si no lo es. De manera que si es bisiesto, solo se suma uno a cada día de comienzo

Comment: Me gusta, así me resulta mas fácil saber si es navidad, san Valentin, etc... voy a probar a ver si soy capaz de meter días concretos :)

Comment: ¿Y si es bisiesto? :D

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre para días concretos:

```
<?php
if((date('m') == 12 && in_array(date('d'), range(22,31))) || (date('m') == 1 && in_array(date('d'), 1, 7))){
    echo 'Es navidad';
}
?>
```

Ejemplo para pruebas:

```
<?php
$dateM = 12;
$dateD = 25;

if(($dateM == 12 && in_array($dateD, range(22,31))) || ($dateM == 1 && in_array($dateD, 1, 7))){
    echo 'Es navidad';
}
?>
```

Saludos,